# Error no se pudo recuperar información de la tabla

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio

tengo un problema al intentar agregar un origen de datos desde el asistente utilizando Visual studio 2017, me aparece el mensaje "No se pudo recuperar información del esquema para la tabla o la vista estudiante."
La base de datos esta en access 2013 y ya he agregado la conexion.
El que me pueda ayudar lo agradeceria mucho.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Veo que es la primera vez que participas con nosotros, así que te recomiendo te des una vuelta por el [tour] del sitio para entender cómo funcionamos.

Comment: Me esta pasando lo mismo, he buscado soluciones y nada! me avisas si encontraste solucion!

Comment: Me está pasando lo mismo. ¿Has llegado a alguna solución?